# getting .val of select list that is loaded on through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having trouble getting a `.val` from a select list I am loading on through `ajax`. It seems to only give me the value of the first option, regardless if I change the select itself or not. The weird thing is I checked in the console for both `$("select").val();`, and `$("select").find(":selected");` and the find selected returns an array with he first item and the one i have currently selected. So it seems it is selected the new one and keeping the first item, but `val` is just returning the first item.

I triple checked my document to make sure there wasn't another one somewhere else, and there isn't.

Here's my code:

fist appending my select box (with other things) on the click action

```
  var statusCheck = "<div class='confirmContainer' style='display:none;'><p class='confirmText'>Change Status of item(s).</p><select class='statusChangeUsr' name='statusHere'></select><button class='smallResultsButton submitStats'>Submit</button><button class='smallResultsButton cancelStats'>Cancel</button></div>";
            $(".actionsToolbar3").append(statusCheck);
```

then bringing in the options in the list in the next click

```
 $.ajax(
             {
                 cache: false,
                 url : "/listUserStatuses",
                 type : "GET",
                  success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                    $.each(data.statuses, function() {
                        $(".statusChangeUsr").append("<option value=" + this.id + " >" + this.name + "</option>");
                    });                         
                 },
                 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                 {
                     alert("Error");
                 }
             });
```

then in the third click I go to get the value from the selected option with

```
  $(".statusChangeUsr").val();
```

the problem is, it's returning 3 every time (which is the value of the first option). As mentioned before, I noticed if I put  `$(".statusChangeUsr").find(":selected");` in the developer console(chrome) I get the following -

```
[<option value=​"3">​Active​</option>​, <option value=​"5">​On-Hold​</option>​]
```

The value of 3 being the first item and the value of 5 being the actual selected item. The end goal would be returning the value of the currently selected item (5 in the case above) Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where in your code are you actually calling $(".statusChangeUsr").val()?  In the $(document).ready function?  In a standalone function you call after you load it through ajax?  If you either only have 1 option in the select statement during initialization or you call the class before the class is actually updated, jQuery will fail to recognize the ajax loaded options.

Comment: Looks like as far as jQuery is concerned, both options are selected, otherwise it would only return one element in the find call.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are calling the $(".statusChangeUsr").val(), jQuery might be looking at the originally loaded  initially generated upon the initial page load.  Then, once you change any value with AJAX, jQuery is still looking at the original $(".statusChangeUsr") that was initially loaded into the DOM, not the appended $(".statusChangeUsr") that is currently displayed.

Whenever I load stuff through an AJAX call, I either use an anonymous function or place it directly in the $(document).ready function.  Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change','.statusChangeUsr',function(){
      console.log($('option:selected',this));
    });
});
```